# Reverse the order of a sort using DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a column that has value "n/a" (without quotes) and numbers from 0 - 5, when sorted it shows 0 first and the other way shows n/a first and begins descending, is there a way to make it show n/a and then ascend to 5? I have tried:

```
 oTable.fnSort([[0, 'natural-asc']]);
```

and

```
"aaSorting": [[ 0, "natural-asc" ]],
```

but no luck. Also, is there a way to have it behave correctly when using a special character like $ or €? because so far I haven't been able to make it do so either.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply a different sorting type you should use aoColumns like this:

```
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "natural" },
            null
        ]
```

To use natural sorting you should do the following things:

- include the function for the natural sorting from [this](http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/) page
- define your own sorting function like this:

  jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-asc']  = function(a,b) {
      return naturalSort(a,b);
  };

  jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-desc'] = function(a,b) {
      return naturalSort(a,b) * -1;
  };
- use aoColumns like indicated above

-in any case if you post an example on jsfiddle.net it's easier to help